# Bootstrap content is overlapping on small and xs screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a site and I have two bootstrap rows. On small and xs screen size, the content starts to overlap.

Here a minimal example showing the problem:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oveckc3t/)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='container-fluid impact-main-container'>
    <div class='row'> 
        <div id='impact-header-main-col' class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 impact-header-col impact-header-col1'>
            <h1 class='mobile-only impact-main-header'>Content</h1>
            <h2 class='impact-header'>
                Some paragraph content goes here Some paragraph content goes hereSome paragraph content goes hereSome paragraph content goes here
            </h2>
            <p class='paragraph-normal-size body-p'>
                Some paragraph content goes hereSome paragraph content goes hereSome paragraph content goes hereSome paragraph content goes here
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'> 
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 impact-stats-children-col impact-header-col'>
            <div class='principles-box'>
                <p class='paragraph-normal-size'><span class='HeleveticaLt'>Content<br></span> <span class='HeleveticaHv'>Content Content</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class='principles-box'>
                <p class='paragraph-normal-size'><span class='HeleveticaLt'>Content<br></span> <span class='HeleveticaHv'>Content Content</span></p>
            </div>
            <button class='btn get-facts'>Content Content Content <i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 impact-stats-children-right impact-stats-children-col'>
            <div class='principles-box'>
                <p class='paragraph-normal-size'><span class='HeleveticaLt'>Content Content<br></span> <span class='HeleveticaHv'>Content</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class='principles-box'>
                <p class='paragraph-normal-size'><span class='HeleveticaLt'>Content Content Content<br></span> <span class='HeleveticaHv'>Content Content</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<style type="text/css">


.principles-box {
    background: black;
    color: #797979;
    padding: 15px 23px 15px 14px;
    border-left: 9px solid #DCDCDC;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.get-facts {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 27px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #979797;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    black-space: normal;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.get-facts:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}


/*Phone*/
@media (max-width: 414px) {
    .home-header-col {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .mobile-bg {
        /*background-position-y: 59px;*/
    }

}
/*xs phones*/
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .impact-stats-children-col {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}


.desktop-only {
    display: block;
}
.mobile-only {
    display: none;
}
/*Phone and landscape tablet*/
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .home-header-col {
        top: 90px;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    }
    .desktop-only {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile-only {
        display: block;
    }
    .offset-col {
        left: 0px;
    }

    .fixed-header-logo {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #logo {
        padding: 10 0 10 0px;
    }
    .impact-stats-children {
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        min-width: 114px;
    }
    .impact-main-header {
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md', Arial, sans-serif;
        /*font-size: 45px;*/
        color: black;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .impact-main-container {
        position: static;
    }
    .impact-header-col {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .impact-header-col1 {
        left: 0px;
        top: 103px;
    }
}

.hidden {
    display: none!important;
}

.verticallyCenter {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/* Calc function for Responsice font size: 
    calc(minFontSize px) + (minFontSize-maxFontSize) * (100vh - minScreenWidth)/(maxScreenWidth - minScreenWidth)) 
*/
h1 {
    font-size: calc(30px + (65 - 30) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}
h1.impact {
    font-size: calc(60px + (60 - 60) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}

h2 {
    font-size: calc(25px + (50 - 25) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
    line-height: calc(30px + (55 - 30) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}
p.paragraph-normal-size {
    font-size: calc(19px + (24 - 19) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
    line-height: calc(26px + (31 - 26) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}

p.paragraph-smaller {
    font-size: calc(15px + (20 - 15) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}

p.paragraph-smallest {
    font-size: calc(13px + (15 - 13) * (100vw - 400px)/(1500 - 400))!important;
}
@media(min-width: 1500px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 65px!important;
    }
    h1.impact {
        font-size: 60px !important
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 50px !important;
        line-height: 55px !important;
    }
    p.paragraph-normal-size {
        font-size: 24px !important;
        line-height: 31px !important;
    }

    p.paragraph-smaller {
        font-size: 20px!important;
    }

    p.paragraph-smallest {
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 400px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    h1.impact {
        font-size: 60px !important
    }
    p.paragraph-normal-size {
        font-size: 19px !important;
        line-height: 26px !important;
    }

    p.paragraph-smaller {
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }

    p.paragraph-smallest {
        font-size: 13px !important;
    }
}

/*xs phones*/
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .home-header {
        font-size: 25px !important;
    }
}

.HeleveticaLt {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt';
}

.HelvetivaMd {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md';
}

.HeleticaHv {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv';
}
html{
    color:black!important;
}
                    </style>
```

Everything works fine on a larger screen, but once you shrink the screen to small or extra small the boxes start to overlap with the paragraphs. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this in your css.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
 .impact-header-col1 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 103px; }
```

Top will pull the section below without adjusting anything else. Rather than using top, use

```
 margin-top: 103px
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this issue is that you are setting a `top: 103px;` to your `.impact-header-col1` @ your `max-width: 991px` breakpoint, which is pushing it down 103px

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7dL94um/1/)